# JMeter Synchronizing Timer time out

Tags: timer, timeout, jmeter, synchronization

I am currently working to set a time out for Synchronizing Timer in JMeter source code.

Currently, if groupsize is set to 5, it will wait till 5 threads is ready before executing. Should 1 of the thread is experiencing some kind of error or timeout, the program should not wait indefinitely. Either continue execution with the remaining threads and flag out the error, or reset the error thread.

Any idea how I can do that in the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find SyncTimer#BarrierWrapper and add 2 parameters to await.

Then add these 2 configuration to SyncTimerBeanInfo so that they appear in GUI.

I suggest you open a Bugzilla (enhancement) and contribute a patch either in Bugzilla or through GITHUB:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html
- https://github.com/apache/jmeter

UPDATE (05th july 2014):
You created :

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56691

It has been implemented and is available in nightly build :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

Comment: I've suggested the enhancement on Bugzilla.
Meanwhile, will try to DIY. if it goes well I will post my solution online